# How many weakly compact cardinals can L have?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

**Q1:** Assuming suitable consistency assumptions is the following consistent?

$ZFC+V=L+\text{Existence of class many weakly compact cardinals}$

**Q2:** What is the **weakest** known consistency assumption for proving the above consistency result?

Comment: Weakly compact cardinals relativize down to $L$.

Comment: Just to make what Andres said explicit: the consistency of ZFC+V=L+"there are X-many weakly compacts" is exactly that of ZFC+"there are X-many weakly compacts."

Answer (score 3):

This is equiconsistent with $ZF+$ "There are class many weakly compacts."  If $\kappa$ is weakly compact in $V$, then it is weakly compact in $L$. (See Jech chapter 17.)  Thus the $L$ of any model of $ZF$ + "There are class many weakly compacts" is a model of $ZFC+V=L +$ "There are class many weakly compacts."